# How to test taking a picture without a webcam, using a virtual device

Tags: android

Just delving into Android development, I know *somewhere* last week I saw options for testing apps that utilize the device's camera. If I recall, one of them was to use a webcam. But my PC doesn't have a webcam and now I cannot find those options.

By any chance do you guys know what I'm talking about, or know an alternative solution?

For what it's worth, `onCreate`:

```
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }
    });
```

Then the rest of my code is just what's found here:

http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPhotoView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to enable the camera in the emulator.

Create a new AVD and enable the camera. I'm on a mac so it is possible my AVD creation is different from yours but here is a screen shot of mine:

[image: screen shot of avd manager]

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I'll flag this as the Answer when I can. I only had to create the device once so I guess that's why i didn't remember where I saw it :)